# SQL Count Optimisations

Tags: python, mysql, django

I have been using the Django Rest Framework, and part of the ORM does the following query as part of a generic object list endpoint:

```
`SELECT COUNT(*) AS `__count`
FROM `album`
INNER JOIN `tracks`
    ON (`album`.`id` = `tracks`.`album_id`)
WHERE `tracks`.`viewable` = 1`
```

The API is supposed to only display albums with tracks that are set to viewable, but with a tracks table containing 50 million rows this is query never seem to complete and hangs the endpoint's execution.

All columns referenced are indexed, so I do not know why this is taking so long to execute. If there are any potential optimisations that I might have not considered please let me know.

Comment: So there are indices on the `album_id` and `viewable` columns in the `tracks` table?  Other than this, I don't see any possible optimizations.  You could also run `EXPLAIN` on this query to see what is going on.

Comment: That is correct. :/ I guess I'll have to see if there's a way to override how Django determines it's count, because this query is generated automatically.

The `EXPLAIN` resulted in >20 million rows being selected so I guess it's no wonder that the join is going to take some time...

Comment: 50 million rows is a lot of data.  If you need the results of this query often, perhaps you can cache it somewhere.

Answer (score 2):

For this query:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS `__count`
FROM `album` INNER JOIN 
     `tracks`
     ON (`album`.`id` = `tracks`.`album_id`)
WHERE `tracks`.`viewable` = 1`;
```

An index on `tracks(viewable, album_id)` and `album(id)` would help.

But, in all likelihood a `join` is not needed, so you can do:

```
select count(*)
from tracks
where viewable = 1;
```

For this the index on `tracks(viewable)` will be a big help.

Comment: Assuming `id` is the primary key of `album`, I think it should already be indexed.  +1 for your second query suggestion.

Comment: Thanks, I already have indexes on all mentioned columns though... and my overall goal is to obtain the album records based on the track relation having viewable set to 1, not the tracks themselves.